# Changing all import statements for MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm learning react right now and have a pretty large project using MUI and with v5 the package name changed from `@material-ui/core` to `@mui/material`. I know this is simple but is there a better way than manually changing *all* my import lines from `import x from "@material-ui/core/x"` to `import x from "@mui/material/x"`. Any help is appreciated I've spent too much time on this and MUI docs/release notes are no help on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MUI team wrote some codemods to help you transition from v4 to v5 more smoothly. See [this](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#run-codemods) section for more detail. In your scenario, you can use the [`mui-replace`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-codemod/README.md#mui-replace) codemod to update the import paths to v5:

```
npx @mui/codemod v5.0.0/mui-replace <path>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to follow when migration from V4 to V5. The preset-safe codemod will change import statements to use the new mui libraries post-upgrade. This codemod is what you are looking for.

```
npx @mui/codemod v5.0.0/preset-safe <path>
```

More details here: https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#run-codemods